# Splitting a video into multiple parts

Tags: video, video-editor

I have several large videos that I want to split into parts. The only way to do that I know is to split one part at a time with OpenShot. I have to split, wait a long time, delete the part, split the next part, ...

Is there a better way? I tried to google but it seems all the methods also require splitting one part at a time. This is really inconvenient as I need each video to be split into 20-30 parts. I want to be able to just mark all the split point and come back later and find it all done. Does anyone know a way?

UPDATE:
Now I'm working on a command line solution. I tried this command but the only problem is that there are few seconds of where the video freezes in the beginning (and end) of each output split.

```
avconv -i x.mp4 -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:01:00 -c:v copy -c:a copy out.mp4  -ss 00:01:00 -t 00:01:00 -c:v copy -c:a copy out1.mp4  -ss 00:02:00 -t 00:01:00 -c:v copy -c:a copy out2.mp4  -ss 00:03:00 -t 00:04:00 -c:v copy -c:a copy out3.mp4
```

Comment: You can use command line  ---   ffmpeg -i input.mpg -ss 00:00:10 -t 00:00:30 out1.mpg -ss is the start point in hh:mm:ss from the beginning of your video file   ---  http://superuser.com/questions/31135/split-mpeg-video-from-command-line

Comment: I tried that. the quality of the output is really poor

Comment: If you want to just split the video without re-ecoding it, use the copy codec for audio and video. Try this: -----

ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:50:00 -i largefile.mp4 -acodec copy \
-vcodec copy smallfile.mp4

Comment: I got an error but it worked when I removed the '\' before -vcodec. Except, it didn't split the file. the smallfile is the same length as the largefile and not 50 seconds.

Comment: can you check this solution, if you are familiar with scripts there is a nice script down the bottom yo can try ---   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651654/ffmpeg-how-to-split-video-efficiently

Comment: Actually that script just cuts a video file into smaller chunks of fixed length and may not be of any use to you.

Comment: Yes, I know about it. I need to split a video of an opera into scenes/acts, etc.

Comment: well you can try this --- ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -ss [start] -t [duration] -c:v copy -c:a copy out.mp4   --- source http://superuser.com/questions/377343/cut-part-from-video-file-from-start-position-to-end-position-with-ffmpeg

Comment: This is better. Thanks. When I chain two outputs together the second one is frozen for the first few seconds.

Comment: i believe i read somewhere but im not sure were, that you could also do multiple cuts in one command rather than doing it once every time. Cant remember though

Comment: ya, thats what I did but the second one freezes for a few seconds: ffmpeg -i x.mp4 -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:00:50 -c:v copy -c:a copy out.mp4  -ss 00:00:49 -t 00:02:00 -c:v copy -c:a copy out1.mp4

Comment: I believe that using `copy` codec one can only split videos on i-frames, which can be as rare as once per scene.

Comment: what should I use then?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution that worked for me.

For example:

```
avconv -ss 0 -i x.mp4 -t 180  -vcodec copy -acodec copy -metadata track="1" "Part I.mp4"              
avconv -ss 180 -i x.mp4 -t 164  -vcodec copy -acodec copy -metadata track="2" "Part II.mp4"              
avconv -ss 344 -i x.mp4 -t 185  -vcodec copy -acodec copy -metadata track="3" "Part III.mp4"
```

I had 50 entries and I put them in a script together. I first put skeletons like

```
avconv -ss  -i x.mp4 -t   -vcodec copy -acodec copy -metadata track="  " ".mp4"
```

Then I filled out the -ss and put the titles. After that, I used libreoffice Calc with space as a delimiter. I got the values for -t and track with a formula and dragging.

Answer (score 1):

If you do this often you can try to create a bash script. Start with something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")

FILES=$(ls *.mp4|sort)

let START=0

for FILE in $FILES
do
    echo Processing $FILE
    mkdir "${FILE}-chop"
    for COUNT in {1..59}
    do
        exec avconv -i "${FILE}" -ss $START -t 60 -c:v copy -c:a copy "./${FILE}-chop/${COUNT} - ${FILE}"
        let START=$START+60
    done
done

IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

Keep in mind that it's a very ugly code, and it will probably produce many errors and empty files, and won't work properly if the input file is more than an hour long, but it'll get you started.