# How to cut up a video into uniform parts using a command line tool

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, ffmpeg, avconv

I want to use a command line tool to cut up a video according to a specific interval, say 1 second. If I have a 60 second video, I expect it to be split up into 60 uniform parts. My only other requirement is that there be **no re-encoding**.

I've read two questions on this topic.

- [Split video into multiple parts - in one go](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967706/split-video-into-multiple-parts-in-one-go)
- [Splitting a video into multiple parts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/440227/splitting-a-video-into-multiple-parts)

The 1st thread suggested an untrusted tool that no longer seems to be maintained. The 2nd thread suggested `avconv` to manipulate large segments of video with manual names. As I'll be cutting up these videos into potentially hundreds of smaller parts, the approach is far too tedious. One user offered a Bash script, but admitted this might "produce many errors and empty files". I'll repost this script here for clarity and to encourage a better solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")

FILES=$(ls *.mp4|sort)

let START=0

for FILE in $FILES
do
    echo Processing $FILE
    mkdir "${FILE}-chop"
    for COUNT in {1..59}
    do
        exec avconv -i "${FILE}" -ss $START -t 60 -c:v copy -c:a copy "./${FILE}-chop/${COUNT} - ${FILE}"
        let START=$START+60
    done
done

IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

Is a Bash script like this really the right approach here? Or is there a simpler, more efficient, more reliable tool that I can use for this purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [segment muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment) in `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -i input -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 60 -reset_timestamps 1 -c copy output_%03d.mp4
```

Using `-c copy` enables stream copy mode. The segment muxer will cut on keyframes when stream copying, so the segments may not have an exact duration of 60 seconds. If you need exactly 60 seconds per segment then you will need to re-encode by removing `-c copy` and setting an appropriate GOP size to fit your segment time constraint. For example, a one second GOP for a 25 framerate output is `-g 25` (default is 250).

Comment: This works almost perfectly, except the `segment_time` doesn't seem to allow less than 5 seconds per segment. I've tried `segment_time 1` and `segment_time 0.1`, but the output is always a minimum of 5 seconds. The ffmpeg manual doesn't appear to explain this inconsistency.

Comment: @Introspectre Did you try without `-c copy`?

Comment: Tried it just now, but it's the same duration, unfortunately.

Comment: @Introspectre Add `-g 25` (and omit `-c copy`).